# Deleting unused Excel custom styles in bulk. How?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, styles

I've inherited someone's Excel workbook with multiple worksheets, and have discovered that the problems I'm encountering are due to an abundance of custom styles.

This Microsoft hep file macro counted over 5000+ styles

```
Sub styles()
For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.styles.Count
    Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = ActiveWorkbook.styles(i).Name
Next
End Sub
```

I'm trying to remove all the custom (strange) styles, but keep the default/standard styles.

I've searched for how to do a bulk remove, and keep finding a similar style of macro in the forums. I've chosen the one below but unfortunately the line *mpStyle.Delete* causes an error:

```
Sub ClrStyles()
 Dim mpStyle As Style
  For Each mpStyle In ActiveWorkbook.Styles
   If Not mpStyle.BuiltIn Then
    mpStyle.Delete
   End If
  Next mpStyle
End Sub
```

The error it returns is: *Delete method of style class failed.*

I'm working in Excel 2010, and the Style class does have a delete function, so I'm confused why it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I used the actual name of the error and managed to find this post in StackOverflow:[Remove the unknown format in Cell styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28080025/remove-the-unknown-format-in-cell-styles)

The additional line *mpStyle.Locked = FALSE* solved my issue.

The full code is now:

```
Sub ClrStyles()
 Dim mpStyle As Style
  For Each mpStyle In ActiveWorkbook.Styles
   If Not mpStyle.BuiltIn Then
    mpStyle.Locked = FALSE
    mpStyle.Delete
   End If
  Next mpStyle
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlocking the locked styles resolved the error.

Here is an alternative code

```
Sub StyleClean()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    Dim inSc, ninSc As Boolean

    With ActiveWorkbook
        N = .Styles.Count
        inSc = True

        For i = N To 1 Step -1
            inSc = .Styles(i).BuiltIn
            ninSc = Not inSc
            If ninSc Then
                .Styles(i).Locked = False
                .Styles(i).Delete
            End If
       Next i
    End With
End Sub
```